# Unreal Development Kit Hardware requirements?

Tags: requirements, sdk

I am very interested in trying out the Unreal Development Kit for my own small to medium-sized hobby projects. I am wondering about the minimum hardware requirements.

I have a Vaio Z laptop with dual-core 2.4 GHZ CPU and 2 GB RAM, and graphics chip is GeForce 9300M GS.

Is it even practicable to run UDK on this hardware? Or do I need a "real" desktop PC?

Comment: Not really suitable for SU because of it's "no gaming" clause (see the FAQ), but I'm not 100% sure it would be acceptable on SO either.

Comment: sorry I have no idea what you are talking about. SU? SO?

Comment: @ChrisF - the UDK is a development kit, it is not a game in itself. It is closer to an IDE than to an actual game.

Comment: @gojira666 - ChrisF used shortcuts to refer to this site (Super User: SU) and our sister site dedicated to programming questions (Stack Overflow: SO). Super User has a policy on questions which should or should not be asked here (you can read about it in the FAQ: http://superuser.com/faq), and games are in the category of things which should not be asked about here. However, like I said in my previous comment, I don't think the UDK qualifies as a game, only a development tool.

Answer (score 2):

From this [link](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DevelopmentKitFAQ.html):

> **Q: What are the minimum requirements
>   for UDK?**
>
> A: Here are the minimum and
>   recommended requirements...
>
> Minimum:
>
> - Windows XP SP2 or Windows Vista
> - 2.0+ GHz processor
> - 2 GB system RAM
> - SM3-compatible video card
> - 3 GB free hard drive space
>
> Recommended for Content Development:
>
> - Windows Vista 64 SP2
> - 2.0+ GHz multi-core processor
> - 8 GB System RAM
> - NVIDIA 8000 series or higher graphics card
> - Plenty of HDD space

According to these specifications, your laptop meets the minimum requirements. It will be however a bit on the limit if you want to create your own content, as it will require more RAM.